# Azure App Service is not able to connect to Azure Redis

Tags: java, spring, azure, redis, azure-web-app-service

I have a Java Spring application that i want to deploy on an Azure App Service that will connect to a Redis for Azure. I've already done it with the same application on a different subscription. I've created both the AppService and the Redis connection on Azure. I got the connection strings from Redis and i added to my Java Application, and also i've created a bean like follow:

```
    @Bean
public JedisConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
    JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory();
    jedisConnectionFactory.setHostName(this.jedisHost);
    if (this.jedisPassword != null && !this.jedisPassword.isEmpty()) {
        jedisConnectionFactory.setPassword(this.jedisPassword);
    }
    jedisConnectionFactory.setPort(jedisPort);
    jedisConnectionFactory.getPoolConfig().setMaxIdle(30);
    jedisConnectionFactory.getPoolConfig().setMinIdle(10);
   //        jedisConnectionFactory.setUsePool(true);
    return jedisConnectionFactory;
}
```

when i run the application in my local enviroment everything works fine. The application start and also can connect to Redis.
But when i deploy it on the azure cloud i get:

```
 Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
 JedisConnectionException: Failed connecting to host valuegoredis.redis.cache.windows.net:6380
 JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
 Error creating bean with name 'enableRedisKeyspaceNotificationsInitializer'
```

I also had the same problems when running localy, but i added a firewall rule to include my IP. 
I've also added the IP of the appService found by running nslookup .azurewebsite.net but here nothing changed.

I'm losing my mind trying to figure it out how can i make it works.

Edit: I've tried both jedis ports 6379 and 6380 
[The the blue circled are the IP of my app service and the red are my local IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HkeVM.png)

I'm allowing both SSL and no SSL connection on 6380 and 6379 but nothing seems to work

Comment: `I've also added the IP of the appService found by running nslookup .azurewebsite.net but here nothing changed.` - there's your problem. That's not the *outbound* IP address for your App Service workers, go to your App Service Plan, under Properties there should be a list of *outbound* IP addresses, use those in the firewall exception for Redis, or simply flip the `Allow access to Azure Services` switch to On.

Comment: @evilSnobu where do you see Allow access to Azure Services? Is that in Redis' properties?

Comment: Yes, go to the Firewall blade under your Redis instance.